# AWS SNS NOTIFICATION IN GCM

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

When I try to create end point of SNS application using php.phar SDk and php code I'm getting the permission issue of user.

> **Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\Sns\Exception\AuthorizationErrorException: AWS Error Code: AuthorizationError, Status Code: 403, AWS Request ID: 00ff41fd-1b05-5696-b8c4-0ff21e72467c, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: User: arn:aws:iam::653168:user/xyz is not authorized to perform: SNS:CreatePlatformEndpoint on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:653111873368:app/GCM/SampleApp, User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.8.8 Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.36.0 PHP/5.5.12 thrown in phar://C:/wamp/www/testing/sns/aws2.phar/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 91

Answer (score 2):

```
AWS Error Code: AuthorizationError


user/xyz is not authorized to perform: SNS:CreatePlatformEndpoint
```

I think your error is pretty self-explanatory. Your authentification fails, probably because you didn't specify your access key ID and secret access key.

Comment: I have get this because i am not given permission to SNS in AWS console

Comment: @Pawan Nagar could you explain more about how to give permission to SNS? thanks

Comment: @ Leo Chen You can ask question about it.But if you want to give permission please 
Goto users of AWS and click on yours current user and see permission for that user and allow SNS full permission.

Comment: @Pawan Nagar, thank you, I figured it out right after the comment, but thank you anyway for the response.